# Windows Phone 8 request to REST enabled https hosted service using RestSharp

Tags: .net, windows-phone-8, restsharp

I have a block of code that works then i try it from console application:

```
   var client = new RestClient("https://.../Service.svc/json");
        client.AddDefaultHeader("client_ip", "..");
        var request = new RestRequest("user/auth", Method.POST);
        request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;
        request.AddBody(new { appkey = "..", user = "d..", password = ".." });
        var authorizeResponse = client.ExecuteAsync<AuthResponse>(request, (response) => {
            if (response.ErrorException == null)
            {
                var a = response.Data;
            }
        });
```

Same code deployed to windows phone device returns:
[image]

Why is status code NotFound? Are there any problems accepting certificates from https in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your certificate is self-signed or not from a root authority that is included on the device then you'll need to install the certificate on the device before you can use it.

Also verify that you can reach the server not under SSL to verify that it's not some other connectivity issue. A Fiddler (or similar) trace is good for getting more information on connectivity problems too.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've already solved the issue: traced the call and discovered that a slight different custom http header was expected on the service.